# What causes panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 4 even though array is initialized as dynamic array

Tags: arrays, go, indexing, panic

I have initialized a dynamic array but it shows index out of range.
I have tried giving fixed length also, but it also shows the same error.

Error Description:
`panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 4`

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func missingNumber(nums []int) int {
    arrSum := 0
    arrLen := len(nums) + 1
    for i := 0; i < arrLen; i++ {
        arrSum += nums[i]
    }
    numSum := arrLen * (arrLen + 1) / 2
    missingNumber := numSum - arrSum
    return missingNumber
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    result := missingNumber(nums)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Problem : `arrLen := len(nums) + 1`. should be only `arrLen := len(nums)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change `arrLen := len(nums) + 1` to `arrLen := len(nums)`.

Your array length is 4. the indexes are 0,1,2,3 for this. but when you tried to do  `arrLen := len(nums) + 1` . the `arrlen` value is now `5`. but you have only 4 element. and from your loop you are trying to get a element that is not present in array. that will give you a runtime error and it will panic.

this one will work for you:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func missingNumber(nums []int) int {
    arrSum := 0
    arrLen := len(nums)
    for i := 0; i < arrLen; i++ {
        arrSum += nums[i]
    }
    m := arrLen + 1
    numSum := m * (m + 1) / 2
    missingNumber := numSum - arrSum
    return missingNumber
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    result := missingNumber(nums)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correction in your program to find a single missing number from sequence of natural numbers. You were indexing array nums[len(nums) + 1] beyond the bounds of your array. If allowed this should access random memory and read any garbage value as legitimate and you would not even know about such hard to find bugs. The good thing is Go is checking that you access only those elements in array which are there and not beyond that. [Read this in Go specs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func missingNumber(nums []int) int {
    arrSum := 0
    arrLen := len(nums)
    for i := 0; i < arrLen; i++ {
        arrSum += nums[i]
    }
    //let n be the total natural number: which will be provided plus 1 missing
    n := arrLen + 1
    numSum := n * (n + 1) / 2
    missingNumber := numSum - arrSum
    return missingNumber
}
func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    result := missingNumber(nums)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Alternately you can use range loop to be safe `or _, i := range nums { ...` :

```
package main

import "fmt"

func missingNumber(nums []int) int {
    arrSum := 0
    arrLen := len(nums)

    for _, i := range nums {
        arrSum += i
    }
    //let n be the total natural number; which will be provided plus 1 missing
    n := arrLen + 1
    numSum := n * (n + 1) / 2
    missingNumber := numSum - arrSum
    return missingNumber
}
func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    result := missingNumber(nums)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```